# Why does the function return 'undefined', even though the variable contains the correct result?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have written a function to return the digital root of a number.

However, this function always returns `undefined`, but the variable contains the correct result.

Where is my mistake?

```js
    function nuberRoot(a: number): number {
        let s: number = 0;
        while (a > 0) {
            s += a % 10
            a = Math.floor(a / 10)
        }
        if (s >= 10) {
            nuberRoot(s)
        } else {
            alert(s)  //  s=6
            return s  //  undefined
        }
    }

    alert(nuberRoot(942))  //  undefined
```

Comment: because you don't return anything from the `if` block - try `return nuberRoot(s)` in the if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing return for `if(s>=10)`

```js
function nuberRoot(a){
    let s = 0;
    while(a>0){
        s+=a%10
        a = Math.floor(a /10)
    }
    if (s>=10){
        return nuberRoot(s)
    }
    
    else{
        alert(s)//s=6
        return s//undefined
    }
    
}
alert(nuberRoot(942))//undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is correct but return when s>10. Thanks.

```
if (s>=10){
      return  nuberRoot(s);
    }
```